# How to fetch latest version of SSM parameter on Cloudformation Yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, parameters, aws-cloudformation, ssm

I have a Cloudformation Yaml file where it creates a lot of resources, one of them is an EC2 with Windows. My problem is I need to have this automated selection of the latest AMI, I made a Lambda function where it retrieves newest AMI ID and stores in an SSM parameter, then using the Cloudformation with YAML template I can access to ssm using the following command

```
{{resolve:ssm:parameter_name:version_number_int}}
```

but my problem is that it's not always the same version number, it will be changed everytime when there will be a new AMI, is there any method where I can write to get always the latest version? or to stop versioning or anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Related feature request: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/75

Comment: thanks for commenting, the best result for this task is the answer I choose, it doesn't depend on creating lambda or any other scripts to update custom SSM parameter for the latest AMI ID of windows when there is already a pre defined public SSM parameter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSM Parameter Store provides [public parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-public-parameters.html#parameter-store-public-parameters-ami) to retrieve latest AMIs.

```
# Use public Systems Manager Parameter
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base'

Resources:
 Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, can you please help me what kind of permissions I would need? The response is:
Unable to fetch parameters [aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base] from parameter store for this account.

Comment: Does this command work for you? `aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base`

Comment: the problem was missing "/" on the default value of the parameter before aws! I just uploaded on the cloudformation stack will have to wait to finish and see if it's working, thanks :D

Comment: thanks, the answer is just like you wrote, but for further notice to anyone using, don't forget to add a / before the "aws" in Default Value of the parameter. Thanks Vikyol

Comment: The question is totally different. I summarize it here: how do you RESOLVE an SSM parameter to its latest version?